# How to have Firefox open prg files?

Tags: linux, firefox, gnome

When I click on a `.prg` file, which are just binary files, then if offers me to download it, where I would like it to always open them with the program `/usr/bin/x64`.

I am using Gnome on Linux, if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To associate a file extension with a program, you create a .desktop file (living at ~/.local/share/applications ) first for the program and then specify the association on the mimeapps.list (living too at ~/.local/share/applications ).

For the specific case:

create file ~/.local/share/applications/x64.desktop with the following content (If the x64 application does not have a menu entry):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=x64 Application
GenericName=x64 Application
Comment=Application to open prg files
Exec=/usr/bin/x64 %F
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Categories=Utility
```

Then on the ~/.config/mimeapps.list you can add the line:

```
application/x-extension-prg=x64.desktop
```

To associate the application with the extension (if you know the mimetype, you can replace application/x-extension-prg with the mimetype of the file.

(You can find more information at https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-application-user.html.en or https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html)